# Ampscript and API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, ampscript

Is it true that only Soap/Web Service API can be used with Ampscript?  What about Ampscript and REST API?

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/using_ampscript_with_the_web_service_api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform GET and POST methods to perform REST API calls.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/http_ampscript_functions/

> Create your AMPscript using the functions below and place them in the
>   content areas of landing pages and email messages. For example, you
>   can use the URLEncode() function to encode spaces or non-alphanumeric
>   characters contained in a URL for use by your subscribers.

```
HTTPGet("http://www.example.com")
```

There are also methods to update headers if that's needed, as well. Passing data may also cause some difficulty and the issue is if the result is JSON, there isn't a great way to handle it.

Depending on the situation, you would be better off with SSJS, but if this happening during a send, it's best to get the data prior to sending anything. If it's on a landing page - you would be ok.

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/http_server_side_javascript_functions/

> You can use the HTTP server-side JavaScript functions to perform HTTP
>   GET and HTTP POST actions and use that information as part of your
>   interactions with the ExactTarget application.

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com';
var headerNames = ["MyTestHeader1", "MyTestHeader2"];
var headerValues = ["MyTestValue1", "MyTestValue2"];
var response = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);
```