# Sending out Triggered Send defined in another Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, triggered-send

I'm sending out an email when a user visits a landing page, as described in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155513/trigger-email-from-landing-page-via-ampscript) post.

My question is: Is it possible to invoke a triggered send defined under another Business unit?

Let's say the landing page that the user lands on is hosted under the business unit 'A'. From this landing page, I would like to trigger a triggered send that's defined under business unit 'B'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are being forced to use SFMC server-side languages only, then your best bet is to use REST API via [HTTPPOST or HTTPGET from either AMPscript or SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61501/ampscript-and-api).

Through the REST API you can target different Business Units(BUs) by creating an ['APP'](https://appcenter.s1.marketingcloudapps.com/#app-center) for that BU and using the Client ID and Client secret of that app in your call. You can then just run your REST call to [send the email](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm).

**SAMPLE REST CALLS:** *(ampscript and SSJS)*

AMPScript:

```
HTTPGet("http://www.example.com")
```

SSJS:

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com';
var headerNames = ["MyTestHeader1", "MyTestHeader2"];
var headerValues = ["MyTestValue1", "MyTestValue2"];
var response = HTTP.Get(url, headerNames, headerValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the approach described in the post you reference? It is based on SOAP API, and this allows calls from outside of Marketing Cloud. Hence calling it with AMPscript from another BU shouldn't be a problem. At least in theory.
Let me know if this isn't the right solution.

Best regards
Lukas

Comment: Unfortunately AMPscript Web services can only interact with the BU it is being used on. You cannot interact with other BUs this way.  But if you call SOAP API outside of SFMC Ampscript, SSJS or GTL, then yes this is a viable solution.

Comment: Valid point @Gortonington - I have never tried this myself, but your reply makes perfect sense.